# Swagger cannot create array of objects

Tags: node.js, json, swagger

Hello I'm attempting to create a array of objects in swagger hub

However I seem to be getting an error for seemingly no reason

```
LocationGetAllResponse:
  properties:
    type: array
    items: 
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/LocationObject'


LocationObject:
  type: object
  properties:
    longitude:
      type: number
      example: 1
    latitude:
      type: number
      example: 2
    altitude:
      type: number
      example:
```

I modelled it after the official docs 
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#array

However the error I'm getting is

```
Structural error at components.schemas.LocationGetAllResponse.properties.type
```

should be object

Basically at the type:array its saying it should be an object

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove "properties:":

```
LocationGetAllResponse:
  type: array
  items: 
    $ref: '#/components/schemas/LocationObject'
```